# Sql Server Insert Into table with values stored proc output with other values

Tags: sql-server

Say there is a table

```
CREATE TABLE [Fruit](
[FruitId] [int] NOT NULL Identity(1,1),
[Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar] (255) NOT NULL,
[Param1] [int] NULL,
[Param2] [int] NULL)
```

and stored proc where it takes an input and has an output parameter called @description.
I cannot modify this stored proc.

```
EXECUTE usp_GetFruitDescription @Name, @Description OUTPUT
```

Now I want to do insert into the [Fruit] table, something like the following.

```
INSERT INTO [Fruit]

Values( 
    basket.Name
    ,EXECUTE usp_GetFruitDescription basket.Name
    ,basket.Param1
    ,basket.Param2)
FROM [FruitBasketEntry] basket
WHERE basket.type is not null and basket.id > 6
```

How can this be achieved? I've seen examples of INSERT INTO [table] EXECUTE usp_proc, but I haven't seen it with inserting with other values not from stored proc output. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to pass your procedure a table-type parameter and let the whole in be done in sets, but since you have mentioned that you cannot change the procedure, below is the only "poor performance" option for you.

```
DECLARE @Name        [nvarchar](255)
DECLARE @Description [nvarchar](255)

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT Name
FROM [FruitBasketEntry] 
WHERE [type] IS NOT NULL AND id > 6

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Name

while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) 
BEGIN

    --execute your procedure here
    EXECUTE usp_GetFruitDescription @Name, @Description OUTPUT

    -- Insert Statement here 
    INSERT INTO [Fruit] Values(@Name , @Description)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Name
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that there are actually more columns and edited the question. In that case, should I query Param1, Param2 using Name in the loop?

Comment: well you can add more columns in the select query, just declare more variables and fetch next values into all of those variables and the rest should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this with looping logic.  There is no other way to put an output argument directly into a table.  If the stored procedure returned a table, you could insert those rows into another table.  Or, if you use a stored function instead of a procedure, you could put that directly into a query.

Probably the best way to approach this is with a cursor.  I almost never recommend cursors, but this is one case where it pretty much seems to be required.